# Export via email of each new "value" that gives the terminal Python

Tags: python

I ask you a big favor.
I'm looking for a code in Python, that allows me to send an email every time a new value appears in the terminal.
I give you an example:

View from the terminal:

```
result 1 banana
result 2 apple
```

Right now what I would like to receive is two emails 
One with: result 1 banana
Second with: result 2 apple.

Someone to some idea?
Thank you very much for helping

Answer (score 0):

Try starting here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html

If you are using a web server like Gmail you will have to get your key and put it into your code to be able to push emails.

Other links:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm

https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html

Comment: Yes, I have been see previously this links but, I don’t know how send every single line of terminal output

Comment: I thought you wanted to send them every time you receive a new vote?  That would just be doing what the above docs say every time...